MySQL Table Locks Immediate Metric
This Datadog graph is related to the Table Locks Immediate defined as the "number of times that a request for a table lock could be granted immediately" based on this. For over a year, this graph has remained flat and all of a sudden, this has increased.


How can I investigate this? As far as I can tell, there are no other metrics that have spiked up aside from this.
Which tables would this refer to?
Should I be worried about this uptick?


enable slow queries log and look at the error log as well, best would be if you have complete queue of your program in your mind so you can identify the commands thtat atr causing the locks, you need to do thus only if you fibd problem with error in you app

I do have slow query logs enabled, but what am I specifically looking for there? Also, I checked the error logs too, and it does not give me any hints on what these lock tables are.

if the slow query log bshows nothing the lock have no impact on the queries and like i said, if you don't have problems with errors or slow queires, nothing is to do
